# How to export graphs generated with the dygraphs package in R to png?

Tags: r, dygraphs

How can I export a plot generated with the R package "dygraphs" to a png file?

```
library(dygraphs)
sample_dat <- data.frame(1:1000, rnorm(1000))
dygraph(sample_dat)
```

Comment: `install.packages('webshot') ; ?webshot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hrbrmstr suggested in the comments, try using `webshot`.

```
library(dygraphs)
sample_dat <- data.frame(1:1000, rnorm(1000))
dygraph(sample_dat)
```

This produces the following output in my default web browser (safari in this instance):

[image]

You will notice in the address bar a path to where the file is temporarily stored on your local drive:

[image]

Copy paste that path like in the following:

```
webshot("file:///var/folders/47/71_55p097y94jptwk6t75f8w0000gn/T/RtmpBPhijO/viewhtml2f836e308321/index.html", 
    "dygraph.png")
```

Also note, you may get the following warning if you don't have PhantomJS installed:

> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with
>   webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the
>   phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.

...in which case run `webshot::install_phantomjs()`

Once, `webshot` has saved it, you will notice a new file saved to your working directory:

[image]

Comment: b/c the `webshot` _vignette_ which was totally viewable from doing the steps in the comment was unreadable?

Comment: @hrbmstr well to be fair the issue of screen shooting a file kept locally could throw someone off (not really that complicated I know), I thought I would just provide step by step directions, hence the images. The user who posted the question seems to be new to here so I thought I'd give an extra helping hand with these images (webshot vignette lacks this and in the case of a temporary file I felt it was warranted). But feel free to repost your comment as an answer and I'll remove mine and up vote yours (also I gave you a h/t in my post...)

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian, thanks for the detailed step-by-step instructions. That works perfectly for an interactive workflow. Moreover, is there a way to make it more scriptable like ggplot2's ggsave command?

Comment: @J.Man no problem, sorry I dont know what you mean by scriptable?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Sorry for not being not specific enough. Ideally, I would like to create my graph and save it to a png file just by running the R code, i.e. something like this `dygraph(sample_dat) %>% Save-file-to-graph-command("graph.png")`.

Comment: @J.Man sorry I'm not aware of a method to accomplish that with ``dygraph`` but I know it can be done with ``plotly``

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Nevertheless, thanks for you help. I will have a look at plotly or ggplotly.